# Declaring Custom fading leads to unfilled element? (Tikz/PGF)

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

What is wrong with the following way of declaring fadings using PGF/TikZ?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{FOne}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!100); color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!100);
 color(75bp)=(pgftransparent!0); color(100bp)=(pgftransparent!0)}

\pgfdeclarefading{myfading}{\pgfuseshading{FOne}}

\path[draw,fill=black,path fading=west] (0,-3) rectangle (10,1);

\path[draw,fill=black,path fading=myfading] (0,-8) rectangle (10,-4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that "FOne" is a one-to-one copy of the definition of the PGF definition of "pgf@lib@fade@west", and thus, "FOne" should resemble the "west" path fading. However, the result is this:

[image: Rendered TikzPicture]

So, the custom filling does not lead anywhere. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the `fading` has to be set-up *before* the `tikzpicture` environment:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fadings}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{FOne}{100bp}
{color(0bp)=(pgftransparent!100); color(25bp)=(pgftransparent!100);
 color(75bp)=(pgftransparent!0); color(100bp)=(pgftransparent!0)}

\pgfdeclarefading{myfading}{\pgfuseshading{FOne}}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path[draw,fill=black,path fading=west] (0,-3) rectangle (10,1);

\path[draw,fill=black,path fading=myfading] (0,-8) rectangle (10,-4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! The programmer in me would have expected some kind of error message if the fading needs to be declared before the TikzPicture.